# MySQL displaying 1 result within while loop...however theirs actually 2 results?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I recently combined 2 queries into 1 (to optimize performance)...1 query for checking the count, and the other for the results, the count is to ensure their is actual results their before proceeding with the loop.

**Heres the PHP code:**

```
<?php

    $query = 'SELECT id, title, COUNT(id) FROM submissions ORDER BY sub_time DESC LIMIT 50';

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count = mysql_result($result, 0, 2);

    mysql_data_seek($result, 0); //mysql_result resets the internal pointer...

    if ($count > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ++$i;

            //etc..

        }
    }


?>
```

The problem is it now returns 1 result? - when theirs actually 2 results inside (as I've checked via PHPMyAdmin aswell as running the following code - see below), I've narrowed down the problem, its because the COUNT(id) has been combined with the intial results query; that its behaving like this.

**Because if I do the following:**

```
<?php

    $query = 'SELECT id, title FROM submissions ORDER BY sub_time DESC LIMIT 50';

    $result = mysql_query($query);

        $i = 0;
        while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ++$i;

            //etc..

        }

?>
```

It returns 2 results...

So my question is how do i resolve this but achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you remove the COUNT(id) and use the [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) function to check how many rows were returned before trying to loop through them.

Your code could then look like this:

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT id, title FROM submissions ORDER BY sub_time DESC LIMIT 50';

$result = mysql_query($query);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ++$i;

        //etc..

    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. What happens if you rely on a value in the resultset to tell you how many results there are, and there *are zero records in the resultset?* Now you have to handle two different cases!

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) that typically is used with the `GROUP BY` clause. I don't believe it is meaningful in the query as you used it.